# Firebase real time database error ,My application is stopped when I am trying to run in emulator

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to run my app is stopping and I am getting like

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: koti.fcmdbreadwrite, PID: 2297
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{koti.fcmdbreadwrite/koti.fcmdbreadwrite.MainActivity}:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process koti.fcmdbreadwrite. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
```

Comment: Please share the [minimal code that causes the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

The error you posted tells you not only *what* went wrong, but it even tells you exactly how to fix it.

The problem is:

> Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process

The solution is:

> Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

Before you interact with Firebase, you need to call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()`. If you do that, this crash will not occur.